# Ajax to download gzip file - response data always a string

Tags: javascript, ajax

Consider the API call below that works fine with Postman. Gzipped document appears correctly.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/returngzip/',
        beforeSend: function(request, settings) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Token ' + window.sessionStorage.token);
            settings.xhr().responseType = 'blob';
            settings.xhr().overrideMimeType('text/plain;  charset=x-user-defined');
            settings.processData = false;
        },
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            // data is ALWAYS string ????????
            var blob=new Blob([data], { type: 'application/x-gzip' });
            var link=document.createElement('a');
            link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download="return-gzip.tar.gz";
            link.click();
        }
    });
```

It also seems the generated file that does get downloaded by the javascript is exactly 1/2 the number bytes as actual payload.  Thoughts?

Comment: "data is ALWAYS string ????????" — What did you expect `overrideMimeType('text/plain;` to do?

Comment: So I leave it out, no change. I use: settings.xhr().overrideMimeType('application/x-gzip;  charset=x-user-defined'); No change.

Comment: Are you willing to remove the unnecessary jQuery bits and try `fetch`? Don't have to do anything other than `response.blob()` then set the download. I believe jQuery is getting in you way.